# how to set sentry directory? django

Tags: python, django, path, operating-system

I am trying to set up sentry.
there is this piece of code that I am putting into my `settings.py`
which contains using git (I am still not sure why git is needed here)

somehow I just can't get the git header right.

I have my file structure as...

[image]

I have tried something like but this only gets me as far as parent directory, I believe I need to go one more directory up in order to get where the git head is.

`print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to go up by one more directory, then you can join another `os.pardir` to the current directory:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, os.pardir))
```